# Can you change the options when long pressing the .com button?

Tags: keyboard

When you longpress the `.com` button on the keyboard, (on my 2.2 htc legend anyway) it gives you the options to select `.net` `.com` `.org` `.edu`.

Is it possible to change these to other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the stock keyboards, no. Some 3rd party keyboards may allow this, but I don't know any. There are some keyboards that have additional options too.